# Any alternative to String[] when splitting a String?

Tags: java, string, split

In making a scanner, I want to split apart the input twice:
First remove any spaces with `String.split("\\s+");`
Then split the remaining String into chars with `String.split("(?!^)");`
After removing the spaces, I can't seem to figure out how to make a String that holds the entirely new Array of parts of my String.
With this, I tried `String = String.split()`, and that didn't work.
Google didn't help either.

Comment: Wait are you trying to split on spaces or remove the spaces? Whats the end goal?

Comment: Remove the spaces

Comment: Please show your code instead of trying to describe it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to be overcomplicating this, why not something as simple as:

```
// remove spaces
String a = "abc".replace(" ", "");

// to array of chars
char[] chars = a.toCharArray();
```

Comment: I've never seen the `.replace()` method used.

Comment: @ProgrammingNub So what? Are you saying that you can't use any method unless you've seen it *used*? **Read the documentation** to learn about methods have haven't seen yet. In this case, that would be the **javadoc** of `String`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: @Andreas no, I meant I never realized it was even there.

Comment: @ProgrammingNub So when you want to do something, and don't already know of a method to do it, you **research**, e.g. by reading the documentation of the object in question, to see what else is available. No one can remember all the methods of the Java Runtime Library, so start getting used to scanning it whenever you want to do something new.